# How can I limit events to one event per frame(iteration) in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

*I'm a beginner. Please go easy on me.*

So I'm trying to learn myself programming for the last weeks, and I tried to make a game with Pygame all for myself. I tried to make a Snake game and I think it's almost done. I just have a Bug that keeps showing up:

So if I click 2 buttons too quickly, they will be perceived in one frame (iteration). This leads to the fact that the player either dies on the spot (because he crashes backwards into himself) or that he goes straight ahead.
In the latter case, this leads to bugs that result in the player simply flying through the border or dying before reaching it

Here is the code for the Control:

```
#Control
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #arrows
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and player_moveY <= 0:
                player_moveY = -playerWith
                player_moveX = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player_moveY >= 0:
                player_moveY = playerWith
                player_moveX = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player_moveX <= 0:
                player_moveX = -playerWith
                player_moveY = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player_moveX >= 0:
                player_moveX = playerWith
                player_moveY = 0
```

Here is the Code for the borders:

```
# boundries
    if playerY < 0 or playerY > screen_width:
        runningGame = False
        
    if playerX < 0 or playerX > screen_width:
        runningGame = False
```

Here is the whole Code(Gameloop at 270):
[Codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/GAbjeN)

Is there a way I can remove this Bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pygame.event.poll`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to get a single event from the queue:

> Returns a single event from the queue. If the event queue is empty an event of type pygame.NOEVENT will be returned immediately. The returned event is removed from the queue.

For instance:

```py
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

# [...]
```

---

Another possible solution is to get the sate of the keys by [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) rathe than the keyboard events (in the application loop instead of the event loop.
Ensure that just one of the direction keys is pressed and change the direction:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
sum_keys = keys[pygame.K_UP] + keys[pygame.K_DOWN] + keys[pygame.K_LEFT] + keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]

if sum_keys == 1:
    if  keys[pygame.K_UP] and player_moveY <= 0:
        player_moveY = -playerWith
        player_moveX = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player_moveY >= 0:
        player_moveY = playerWith
        player_moveX = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player_moveX <= 0:
        player_moveX = -playerWith
        player_moveY = 0
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player_moveX >= 0:
        player_moveX = playerWith
        player_moveY = 0
```